# How to XML file to create a workbook with two sheets

Tags: c#, xml

This is my code:

```
public void WriteToXml()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<int>> Table;
    Table = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    Table.Add("A0", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("B0", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("C0", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("D0", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("A1", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("B1", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("C1", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("D1", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("A2", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("B2", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("C2", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("D2", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("A3", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("B3", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("C3", new List<int>());
    Table.Add("D3", new List<int>());
    foreach (string key in Table.Keys)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Table[key].Add(i);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    int TableLength = Table[Table.Keys.ElementAt(0)].Count();
    xml.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    xml.Append("<Sheet Id=\"1\">\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TableLength; i++)
    {
        xml.Append("<Row>\n");
        foreach (string key in Table.Keys)
        {
            xml.Append("<" + key + ">" + Table[key].ElementAt(i) + "</" + key + ">\n");
        }
        xml.Append("</Row>\n");
    }
    xml.Append("</Sheet>\n");
    xml.Append("<Sheet Id=\"2\">\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TableLength; i++)
    {
        xml.Append("<Row>\n");
        foreach (string key in Table.Keys)
        {
            xml.Append("<" + key + ">" + Table[key].ElementAt(i) + "</" + key + ">\n");
        }
        xml.Append("</Row>\n");
    }
    xml.Append("</Sheet>\n");
    //Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\310217955\Documents\Test\test.xml"))
    {
        file.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an XML file, which when opened in Excel will have two sheets with a table in each sheet. However, the xml file currently generated causes an error when opened via Excel. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: If you are generating an (OpenXml-based) Excel, file I highly recommend using a 3rd Party library such as [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) or [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). Trying to do so using the above approach will be painful and difficult to maintain.

Comment: What aren't using one of the Net Xml libraries?

Comment: I found out that this way was easier to convert my table to an xml document